# Console Application -variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, console-application

I want to import variables Console Application Ex; `application.exe -variable1 -variable2 -variable3` And i want to run this exe in Web Application.

Shortly,
First problem; How to import variables out of exe?
Second problem; How to call exe in Web Application from Local Server? I think codes looks like;

```
CallExeInWebApplicationFromServer("ExePath\app.exe -variable1 -variable2");
```

Finally sorry my bad english..

Comment: Check here http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start and look at the "Run Legacy Program" example. You should be able to work that example to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parameters using the `Environment.CommandLine` value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/commandlineparser.aspx

and you can run your application using the `Process.Start`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Comment: I dont want get, i want import variable. Please read my post.

Comment: @SonerÇolak the process start page on msdn have an example with import variables.

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid to call executable file from your web app because is very unsafe.

It would be better if your web application store somewhere (let's say to a Sql Table) the action it wants to take (in this case call the .exe file) along with the parameter it needs. Another process could pooling this table and call your .exe file (you will just need to get the command to launch from the Sql Table)